# Deploying with TFS keeps DEBUG directive on

Tags: debugging, azure, tfs, preprocessor-directive, build-definition

I'm just realizing that the `DEBUG` processor directive remains on when deploying with TFS, is there a way to change the settings in the TFS/Azure website or in the build definition, and not in the local solution configuration?

I still want the local solution to remain as debug, only the deployed output should become release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the AzureContinuousDeployment template, you can set it to use Release when building.

Edit or create your build definition and go to the Process section.  Under `2. Basic`, you'll see `Configuration To Build`, where you will be able to select Release and then the platform to target (any CPU will work fine for Azure website).

Comment: I'm using TFS build, but I found it, I hope this will solve the issue.